# Error while getting Facebook SDK NuGet

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am having trouble getting Facebook SDK by Outercurve.

Error:

> Could not install package 'Facebook 7.0.6'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have tried to do some modification on the SDK and lower down android version but in all cases, it failed to download. I tried on new projects as well to assure it's not something wrong with the current project. At the moment no other solution crosses my mind. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Jason's advice, I find a solution. There is a [Facebook Component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk) for Xamarin. You cannot use any arbitrary Nuget package with Xamarin - it has to be one that targets a compatible framework. Unfortunately the Nuget manager does not allow you to easily filter out incompatible packages.

Comment: Worked. cool part of it is the sample solutions within the component. thanks!